# Installing multiple packages with one yum command AND failing if any of them is unavailable

Tags: yum

I want to install multiple packages with one `yum` command, and fail if any of them is unavailable. However, while `yum install -y foobar` would fail since there's no `foobar` package, `yum install -y mysql foobar` would install `mysql` and silently ignore the missing `foobar` package.

Is there a good way of checking all the requested packages were installed? My best idea is to look for the `No package .* available` string in the output, so basically:

```
yum install -y mysql foobar | grep 'No package .* available'; [ ! $? = 0 ]
```

The problem is that this depends on an error message printed by `yum`, which may change over time. `grep` also swallows the output of `yum`, which may make complicate debugging problems other than unavailable packages in the future.

Comment: Hey, considering you're using `yum` and not `dnf`, this might actually be behaviour specific to your version of `yum`. I'd like to be be able to reproduce – which Linux distro is this? `dnf` (and the `yum` that it emulates) just quits right away when running `yum install -y mysql foobar`, and tells me `foobar` cannot be found, and doesn't try to install `mysql`. **Are you sure** that `yum` goes ahead and installs `mysql` in your scenario? Is this maybe a 7-or-earlier RedHat?

Comment: Hi, it's happening in an Amazon Linux 2 Docker container I'm building. `yum --version` says it's `rpm-4.11.3-48.amzn2.0.2.x86_64` and `yum-3.4.3-158.amzn2.0.6.noarch`

Comment: The good news is that yum is very unlikely to change, then. `yum`'s not being developed anymore – the yum people are working on `dnf` now (which, by the way, would've been awesome for you to have, as, well, it's a python library and interfacing with it to get things like (mathematical meaning of the word) sets of available packages and intersecting them with other sets is quite straightforward). So, I'd honestly just parse the output of `yum list --available mysql foobar neovim zsh…`

Comment: Maybe in case of a missing package, yum ask weather to install the remaining packages found and the `-y` answer yes automatically. What happens if instead you redirect `yum` stdin to `/dev/null` ? Does it select the default choice ? I am not very familiar with RedHat based distro and lack one to test for now.

Comment: It's not the `-y` option, I'm afraid. For example `yum install bar baz` exits successfully without asking any questions. Furthermore, I need `-y` since I'm working on a `Dockerfile`, I can't do interactive installations.

Comment: If you just want to know afterwards what has been installed, `rpm -q foobar` would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `--setopt=skip_missing_names_on_install=False` argument makes `yum` fail in case any of the packages would be missing:

```
yum install -y --setopt=skip_missing_names_on_install=False mysql foobar
```